# 1st order nonhomogeneous differential equation with sinusoidal input (with phase shift)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

this d.e. is killing me! It's been a while since I took a d.e. class and was hoping for some help with a problem.

The equation is: $$L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri=20\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$

It is the phase shift that is getting me. I can get the transient solution but I cannot figure out the steady state.

The method of unknown coefficients doesn't seem to work. (I imagine because of the phase shift)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Change to $T=t+\frac{25º}{800}$ and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$Li'+Ri=20\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$
$$i'+\frac R Li=\frac {20}L\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$
Use integrating factor
$$(ie^ {\frac R Lt})'=e^ {\frac R Lt}\frac {20}L\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$
$$ie^ {\frac R Lt}=\frac {20}L\int e^ {\frac R Lt}\sin(800t+25^\circ)dt$$
substitute $s=800t+25 \implies ds=800dt$
$$ie^ {\frac R Lt}=\frac 1 {40L}\int e^ {\frac R L(s-25)/800}\sin(s)ds$$
$$i(t)=\frac 1 {40L}e^ {-\frac R L(\frac 1{32}+t)}\int e^ {\frac {Rs} {800L}}\sin(s)ds$$
Just integrate now...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  $$A\sin(800t+25^\circ)+B\cos (800t+25^\circ)?$$

for a particular solution?

It should work out.

Just take derivative and plug in

$$L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri=20\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$

to Find A and B.

Answer (score 0):

$$L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri=20\sin(800t+25^\circ)$$
HINT :

If the phase shift is only that is getting you, simply make the phase shift disappear from the equation.

$\sin(a+b)=\cos(b)\sin(a)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$
$$L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri=20\cos(25^\circ)\sin(800t)+20\sin(25^\circ)\cos(800t)$$
Now, there is no phase shift in it.